# How to have the Facebook comments shown in the count where Wordpress comments count appears?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, facebook

I am using a template theme which had WordPress comments enabled on the website by default. With the Facebook Comments plugin, I have been able to use Facebook Comments in place of the Wordpress comments.

**However, with every post metadata,

- ***the comment count shows zero/No comments***

  even though the 'Facebook comments' exist (courtesy the plugin installed).**

As in the image below:

[image: e.g. 'No Comments' in the metadata above even though 2 comments existed]

**How do I have the facebook comments count shown there instead?**

I have no knowledge of php coding beyond the syntax and method calls.

If this is tedious for a novice, I can live with hiding 'No comments' from the metadata as well. FYI, It appears as an element of the `<li>` element with no class type mentioned in the page source.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with FB Comments plugin, but you could add html tag:

```
<span class="fb-comments-count" data-href="LINK_TO_PAGE"></span>
```

Where *No Comments* is shown (page.php template I guess), this will get number of comments from facebook for post.